# Get shelf clean version

Tags: tfs, unshelve

Is there a way to get a shelved version "as is", without any regard to current client version? I did "undo all pending changes", then unshelved, and still the end result was a merge between my previous version, and the shelved one.

Answer (score 0):

Shelve what you've got checked out but uncheck "preserve pending changes locally". So your workspace is now clean, then unshelve the other shelfset.

Or just setup another workspace.

Or click "My work" then suspend and then unshelve the other shelfset.

Lots of ways to do it.